# Can anybody give me an average CMB noise?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, noise

I am writing some paper now & wanted to know what is an average cosmic microwave background (CMB) noise in dB? Just an average, not interested in peak power, as it's going to be ignored for this topic.

And can anybody point me out some research about it? Some scientific paper?

Comment: You want the power level in dBm? It depends on how much of the sky you take. The graph by @Anna has it per steradian. And the vertical is intensity, looks like per unit freq, and something like MJY/sr. The last is steradian, MJ MAY be mega joules, and Y MAY BE 1/per year. If so you have it, just change units and turn into dBm, but i just don't know for sure. You'll have to do some digging.

Answer (score 1):

The CMB is the [most perfect fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Features) to [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) radiation

[image: bb]

> Graph of cosmic microwave background spectrum measured by the FIRAS instrument on the COBE, the most precisely measured black body spectrum in nature.[7] The error bars are too small to be seen even in an enlarged image, and it is impossible to distinguish the observed data from the theoretical curve.

The Black Body curve is characterized by a unique temperature, T, coming from the fit to the [Planck radiation formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html#c3).

\begin{equation}\left<E\right>=\frac{h \nu}{e^{h\nu/kT}-1}.\end{equation}

> what is an average cosmic microwave background (CMB) noise in dB

I suppose by "noise" you mean differences in the black body fit, ( because the experimental errors are very small) for different regions of space. These are a tool used to study cosmological features , [as here, for example](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9903232).

> The ten's of micro-Kelvin variations in the temperature of the cosmic microwave background (CMB) radiation across the sky encode a wealth of information about the Universe. The full-sky, high-resolution maps of the CMB that will be made in the next decade should determine cosmological parameters to unprecedented precision and sharply test inflation and other theories of the early Universe.

So your answer is *"tens of micro-Kelvin variations in temperature"*